# Is pleasuring yourself without ejaculation permitted?

Tags: halal-haram, sex, masturbation

I know masturbation is haram in Islam, but what about simulating one's sex organs without ejaculation? If I fear I may masturbate, is it permissible to touch or simulate my genitals but just not ejaculate?

Comment: In English, "simulating one's sex organs without ejaculation" would still be masturbation ([dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/masturbation): the stimulation or manipulation of one's own genitals, especially to orgasm).

Answer (score 1):

as far as I know [23:5](http://legacy.quran.com/23/5)  and [23:6](http://legacy.quran.com/23/6) are the verses that scholars depend on as (daleel - دليل - evidence ) that masturbation is not allowed

> وَالَّذِينَ هُمْ لِفُرُوجِهِمْ حَافِظُونَ (5) **إِلَّا** عَلَىٰ `أَزْوَاجِهِمْ` أَوْ `مَا مَلَكَتْ أَيْمَانُهُمْ` فَإِنَّهُمْ غَيْرُ مَلُومِينَ (6)
>
> And they who guard their private parts (5) **Except** from their `wives` or those their `right hands` possess, for indeed, they will not be blamed (6)

the only 2 exceptions that the verse declared are the `wives` and the those their `right hands` possess. -which of curse are not exist in our days-

so scholars said that anything that is not fall inside that exception might not be allowed unless there is another (daleel - دليل - evidence )from the Quran or sunna permits it, and as far as I know there is no other daleel declared more exceptions. **So, I think what you ask about is obviously didn't fall in that exception**.

---

*please be aware that I'm not a scholar or mofty I just told you what I know, so please wait until a scholar tell us his word.*

Comment: I believe there is another translation of this very verse where instead of "And those who guard their private parts" it says "And those who guard their chastity". Technically, this would mean that masturbation breaks your chastity.